# JavaScript: How to create nested array from string

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, multidimensional-array, cheerio

I have the following code and I need to create a nested array from which, I will generate a multilevel ordered list.

```
var htmlContent2 = '<div id="header"><p class="headpara">Header content</p><p class="one">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur:</p><p class="two">Perferendis iure doloremque iusto adipisci facilis.</p><p class="two">Asperiores impedit officiis cumque molestias at rerum consequuntur!</p><p class="one">More dummy text.</p> <p class="two">Additional dummy text: </p> <p class="three">Asperiores impedit officiis.</p> <p class="three">Lolestiae asperiores ad repellat est obcaecati.</p> <p class="two">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</p> <p class="notelem">Dignissimos maiores facere consequuntur quod.</p> <p class="one">Ea  excepturi aperiam.</p></div>';

var $ = cheerio.load(htmlContent2);
var allList = [];
var manipulatedContent = $('#header').each(function (i, elem) {
    var level1 = [],
        level2 = [],
        level3 = [],
        level4 = [],        
        item1 = $('.one').html(),
        item2 = $('.two').html(),
        item3 = $('.three').html(),
        item4 = $('.notelem').html();
    level1[i] = item1;
    level2[i] = item2;
    level3[i] = item3;
    level4[i] = item4;
    allList.push(item1, [item2, [item3, item4]]);

});
console.dir(allList);
```

With my current code I can only produce the following array:

```
[ 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur:',
  [ 'Perferendis iure doloremque iusto adipisci facilis.',
    [ 'Asperiores impedit officiis.',
            'Dignissimos maiores facere consequuntur quod.']]]
```

But the desired result array:

```
['Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur:',
    ['Perferendis iure doloremque iusto adipisci facilis.',
        ['Asperiores impedit officiis.',
            ['Dignissimos maiores facere consequuntur quod.']]]];
```

How can I achieve this using JavaScript or any better method with cheerio.js?

My objective is to create a nested ordered list from a poorly formatted html as shown in the sample content (htmlContent2).

Your help will be very much appreciated.

Comment: It kind of looks like all you need to do is change `allList.push(item1, [item2, [item3, item4]]);` to `allList.push(item1, [item2, [item3, [item4]]]);`

Comment: When I use the above code the resulting content is not quite what I need. I get the following: [ 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur:',
  [ 'Perferendis iure doloremque iusto adipisci facilis.',
    [ 'Asperiores impedit officiis.', [Object] ] ] ]
I am using cheerio.js to generate the nested array.

Comment: Works fine for me. See chester's answer for proof it works.

Comment: I will try with regular jQuery, at the moment I am using cheerio.js to generate the array. In the last element output like this [Object] ] ] ] instead of the content.

Comment: That's just the output generated by `console.dir()`, which apparently stops at a certain depth in order to avoid tons and tons of output for complex objects. The actual object does contain the data structure you need.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @Chris G commented:

```js
//var htmlContent2 = '';
//var $ = cheerio.load(htmlContent2);
var allList = [];
var manipulatedContent = $('#header').each(function (i, elem) {
    var level1 = [],
        level2 = [],
        level3 = [],
        level4 = [],        
        item1 = $('.one').html(),
        item2 = $('.two').html(),
        item3 = $('.three').html(),
        item4 = $('.notelem').html();
    level1[i] = item1;
    level2[i] = item2;
    level3[i] = item3;
    level4[i] = item4;
    allList.push(item1, [item2, [item3, [item4]]]);

});
console.dir(allList);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="header"><p class="headpara">Header content</p><p class="one">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur:</p><p class="two">Perferendis iure doloremque iusto adipisci facilis.</p><p class="two">Asperiores impedit officiis cumque molestias at rerum consequuntur!</p><p class="one">More dummy text.</p> <p class="two">Additional dummy text: </p> <p class="three">Asperiores impedit officiis.</p> <p class="three">Lolestiae asperiores ad repellat est obcaecati.</p> <p class="two">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</p> <p class="notelem">Dignissimos maiores facere consequuntur quod.</p> <p class="one">Ea  excepturi aperiam.</p></div>
```

Comment: Hello Chester, the generated array does not seem to be valid.

Comment: @Manou, not sure what you mean? It is identical to the desired result you included in your question.

Comment: I just checked again and it worked fine actually. Thanks for your help.